# How to reduce memory when load all data in select list

Tags: php, laravel

I use a select box to select a particular member. In my member table have more than 50k records. I added an index for `member_id`. How can I reduce memory when loading the page?

**Query**

```
$memberslist = Members::select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name',
    'member_id', 'phone')
    ->orderBy(('first_name', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

[image]

Comment: use the ``chunk`` or ``lazy`` method of loading data from the database. Read https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#chunking-results

Comment: Also, you can cache the data once and return the cached data next time. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#storing-items-in-the-cache

Comment: Rather than an obnoxiously large `<select>` element, consider using an [`autocomplete`](https://www.algolia.com/blog/engineering/how-to-implement-autocomplete-with-javascript-on-your-website/) component. Far nicer from a UX perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination (I believe you're using laravel - it makes it very easy)

Pagination is a technique which splits the returned records into groups and displays them over multiple pages.

Comment: I display all data's in select box

Comment: @Karthik There's a lot of JavaScript libraries that allow you to create dropdowns with options that are loaded via AJAX. You can use one of those in combination with pagination to load things when needed rather than pre-emptively

Comment: Displaying 50k items in a select box is a crime against usability. Why not use search box with dynamic data loading, like https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: @Karthik it might be better to either simply display a list of radio inputs on a page and then paginate that, or the far cleaner way would be to just have a text input in which the user inputs the name/phone number of a user!

Answer (score 0):

You can start by limiting the number of rows returned. Unlikely you really need all 50k rows at once. Using `limit()` may be useful.

Alternatively, if you do some kind of processing with all the records on every request, see if you can do that in the database directly or use some sort of caching.